# Setting transactional-table properties results in external table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, parquet, impala

I am creating a *managed table* via `Impala` as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name
    STORED AS parquet
    TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='false', 'insert_only'='false')
    AS ...
```

This should result in a `managed table` which does not support `HIVE-ACID`.
However, when I run the command I still end up with an external table.
Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out in the [*Cloudera* documentation](https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.2/hive-metastore/topics/hive-hms-table-storage.html#:%7E:text=Table%20properties%20do%20contain%20one%20or%20more%20ACID%20properties%20set%20to%20true.&text=Spark%20has%20no%20access%20to,HIVEMANAGESTATS%2C%20HIVECACHEINVALIDATE%2C%20.%20.%20.) that neglecting the *EXTERNAL*-keyword when creating the table does not mean that the table definetly will be managed:

> When you use EXTERNAL keyword in the CREATE TABLE statement, HMS stores the table as an external table. When you omit the EXTERNAL keyword and create a managed table, or ingest a managed table, HMS might translate the table into an external table or the table creation can fail, depending on the table properties.

Thus, setting `transactional=false` and `insert_only=false` leads to an `External Table` in the interpretation of the *Hive Metastore*.

Interestingly, only setting `TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='false')` is completly ignored and will still result in a managed table having `transactional=true`).